# How to run google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate google maps in my flutter app, but it is giving an exception every time I run it on physical device.

I have generate Google API key, the proper way and now i have two android mobiles, one is Samsung Galaxy A70 which is running on Android 9, and although getting an exception, it is running fine in it. then I tried on my second phone Realme master edition, it is running on android 12, and as I open the screen of maps it loads map but I am not able to drag it or anything. I have tried on emulator too, its android 11, and there are no exceptions but as I open the screen of maps it loads map but I am not able to drag it or anything.

This is the terminal since map application starts, two exceptions are below:

```
    D/MapsInitializer( 4050): preferredRenderer: null
D/zzca    ( 4050): preferredRenderer: null
I/zzca    ( 4050): Making Creator dynamically
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Unsupported class loader
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule( 4050): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000
I/DynamiteModule( 4050): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203115000
V/DynamiteModule( 4050): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Unsupported class loader
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API( 4050): Google Play services client version: 12451000
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/Google Maps Android API( 4050): Google Play services package version: 223316028
I/Google Maps Android API( 4050): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
D/MapsInitializer( 4050): loadedRenderer: LEGACY
D/zzca    ( 4050): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API( 4050): Google Play services package version: 223316028
I/Google Maps Android API( 4050): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 4050): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out( 4050): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 4050): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/PlatformViewsController( 4050): Using hybrid composition for platform view: 0
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 4050): tagSocket(130) with statsTag=0x30001101, statsUid=-1
E/GoogleMapController( 4050): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
I/bb      ( 4050): Successfully registered with Phenotype.
D/ViewRootImpl@a868e4[MainActivity]( 4050): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2400] new=[0,0][1080,2400] result=0x1 surface={true 499103596544} changed=false
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/ImageReader;->newInstance(IIIIJ)Landroid/media/ImageReader; (dark greylist, linking)I/System.out( 4050): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 4050): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/DynamiteModule( 4050): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 4050): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:7
I/DynamiteModule( 4050): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 7
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Unsupported class loader
W/xample.megatec( 4050): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/SnapshotHandler( 4050): Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.megatech, using defaults.
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050): Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.megatech, may result in stale flags.
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.megatech, sha256=[4cdb70abab312ccc7702ffd88cd51610ea4ed3cdc2e4f72e894ee06d822f1d0a], atk=false, ver=223316028.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at ahv.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at ahv.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at ajf.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at xy.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at ya.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):0)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)   
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.megatech, sha256=[4cdb70abab312ccc7702ffd88cd51610ea4ed3cdc2e4f72e894ee06d822f1d0a], atk=false, ver=223316028.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at es.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at rk.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):4)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at iz.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at jy.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at jy.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at jy.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at kc.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223316065@22.33.16 (100400-0):69)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
W/MobStoreFlagStore( 4050):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

My code is:

```
GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: controller.center, zoom: 18),
          mapType: controller.type,
          markers: controller.markers,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it add this code under application in your `manifest` file:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Its probably because you don't have `google play services` installed. If you ran the app on your actual phone it would work just fine.

Comment: Hello brother, I am using physical device or actual phone, I get to know that I am getting an exception by looking at terminal, but if i build relwase apk, it does not work too. I have checked in my devices, google play services is activated too. and the line you mentioned above, where to put it in Android-Menifest.xml?